# Porque mi codigo me marca este errror: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base?

Tags: python

Hola amigos estoy creando un programa en Python y me da ese error. Aquí les dejo mi codigo para saber si me pueden ayudar,muchas gracias.

```
from pyrecord import Record
import numpy as np
from random import randint

Rcuentas =      Record.create_type("Rcuentas","nro_cuenta","apellido","nombre","dni","tipo_cuenta","saldo","activa",                         
                        nro_cuenta=0,apellido=' ',nombre=' ',dni=' ',tipo_cuenta=0,saldo=0.0,activa=True)


def leer(vector, archivo):
    archivo = open(archivo, 'r')
    i = 0
    for linea in archivo:
        vector[i] = Rcuentas()
        separar =  linea.split(' - ')
        cuenta = int(separar[0])      
        apellido = separar[1]
        nombre = separar[2]
        dni = separar[3]
        t_cuenta = int(separar[4])
        saldo = float(separar[5])
        activo = bool(separar[6])
        print(vector[i],cuenta,apellido,nombre,dni,t_cuenta,saldo,activo)
        i += 1
    archivo.close()
    return i

def imprimir_cuentas(registro):
    print(registro.cuenta,registro.apellido,registro.nombre,registro.dni,registro.t_cuenta,registro.saldo,registro.activo)


def main():
    cantidad_maxima = 1000
    cant_real = 0
    cuentas = np.empty([cantidad_maxima,], dtype=Rcuentas)

    cant_real = leer(cuentas, "cuentas.txt")

    for i in range(cant_real):
        imprimir_cuentas(cuentas[i])
   


main()
```

este es el codigo no se si tambien les tendria que mostrar el archivo txt pero si asi me pueden ayudar a resolver este error se los agradeceria.

Comment: Si, yo voy a necesitar el txt. Podrías agregar en tu pregunta un ejemplo del archivo txt que abres por favor?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: El error de debe a que estas tratando de convertir un string a int pero el string no puede ser expresado en base 10, deberías verificar tu archivo txt,. Sería de ayuda que pongas tu txt